Estimate which uniform category
Problem:
A scalar value $\theta$ is drawn from one of $N$ continuous, uniform distributions $U\left[w_{1}, w_{2} \right]$, $U\left[ w_{3}, w_{4} \right]$, $\cdots$ $U\left[w_{N-1}, w_{N} \right]$, in which $U\left[w_{k-1}, w_{k} \right]$ is uniform on interval $\left[ w_{k-1}, w_{k} \right]$. I estimate the true value $\theta$ with estimate $\hat{\theta}$. This estimate may be or may not be inside any one of the sets $\left[ w_{k}, w_{k+1} \right]$, where $1\le k \le N-1$.
My goal is to decide which category (interval) $\theta$ was drawn from with data $\hat{\theta}$. My question follows below.
Routine application of conditional probability and Baye's gives (for interval $k$):
Pr$\left(\theta \in \left[ w_{k-1}, w_{k} \right] \vert \, \hat{\theta} \right)$ $=$ $\cfrac{\text{Pr}\left( \hat{\theta} \,\vert \, \theta \in \left[ w_{k-1}, w_{k} \right] \right) \text{Pr}\left( \theta \in \left[ w_{k-1}, w_{k} \right] \right) }{\text{Pr}\left( \hat{\theta} \right)}$.
The total probability for the estimate of $\theta$ is:
$\text{Pr}\left( \hat{\theta} \right)$ $= \displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{N} \text{Pr}\left( \hat{\theta} \vert \,\theta \in \left[ w_{n-1}, w_{n} \right] \right) \text{Pr}\left( \theta \in \left[ w_{n-1}, w_{n
} \right] \right)$.
I can replace $\text{Pr}\left(\bullet \right)$ with densities, if I am not mistaken.
Comment:
This problem is reminiscent of simpler problems, in which several factories share the market with light bulbs, each factory has a certain fraction of defective light bulbs, and the problem is to determine the probability a defective bulb came from a particular factory. What is unlike such problems is that the bulb is deterministically defective, and in my case, I need to infer what factor the bulb came from, based on estimate $\hat{\theta}$.
Questions:
[1] Is this approach defensible?
[2] Should I just compute such a probability for each interval, and select the highest probability category ($k$ for greatest Pr$\left(\theta \in \left[ w_{k-1}, w_{k} \right] \vert \, \hat{\theta} \right)$) as a ``interval estimate'' or:
[3] Can anyone recommend an estimator or more modern methodology that reduces variance or increases true positive rate?
[4] Comment: I'm actually seeking a generalization to this problem in which some intervals are unknown and I have additional constraints on the intervals (strictly positive and finite, some overlap, etc...), but I will focus on the easy problem first.
I concede I never used the uniformity of the distributions in this descript. For those curious, this is an abstraction of a real, geophysical problem (not homework help).
